# React - updated state observed with useSelector() doesn't render new components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using Redux Toolkit and Redux Thunk. I successfully get my data asynchronously from a data source back into my component. Inside my component, I can observe the data coming with useSelector: `const booksData = useSelector((state) => state.books);`

At this point, I would like to loop the books I'm getting and render my `Book` component for each book data I'm getting:

```
  const renderBooks = (books) => {
    books.map((book) => {
      console.log(book.id);
      <Book props={book}/>;
    });
  };
```

Problem is, I can see this renderBooks is called and `bookId`s logged for each book. The `<Book>` component is not rendered though.

Am I missing something obvious? Isn't the `useSelector` a state like `useState` so it should trigger rendering once updated?

Thanks in advance.

Rendering code (simplified to cut noise):

```
  return (
    <React.Fragment>

{/*some usual HTML here */}

      <div>{renderBooks(booksData.books)}</div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the values:

```
  const renderBooks = (books) => {
  return  books.map((book, index) => {
      console.log(book.id);
     return <Book key={index} props={book}/>;
    });
  };
```

Comment: I KNEW it was something silly! Thanks a lot!